# Hom and Tensoring with the Dual in Category O

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In general, for infinite dimensional vector spaces, we know that $V^* \otimes W$ and $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ are not isomorphic, with $V^* \otimes W$ being isomorphic instead to the subspace of finite rank maps.

Now, suppose instead that $V$, $W$ are modules in Category $\mathcal{O}$ for some semi-simple Lie algebra (or, more generally a symmetrizable Kac-Moody algebra). If, instead of the full dual $V^* = \prod_\lambda V^*_\lambda$,  we use the restricted dual $V^\vee := \bigoplus_\lambda V^*_\lambda$ (to stay inside of $\mathcal{O}$), do we recover a statement like $V^\vee \otimes W \cong \text{Hom}(V,W)$?

Comment: You need to be careful. In order to take this dual (which I would usually prefer to call the graded dual rather than the restricted dual, since it really does depend on a grading of the underlying vector space), you also need to "twist" the action to get back into category $\mathcal{O}$. But it will still not work quite this nicely, since the Hom can still recover the "usual" dual by taking $W$ to be the trivial module, in which case the dimensions don't match.

Comment: I guess the obvious replacement for Hom would be $\operatorname{Hom}(V, W) := \bigoplus_\lambda \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V_\lambda, W_\lambda)$, and this would be isomorphic to $V^\vee \otimes W$ as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. However, note that it's pretty rare that the tensor product of objects in $\mathcal{O}$ is again in $\mathcal{O}$.